# Substitute given pattern with a random one with awk

Tags: awk

I have an XML file that has a set of entries like this:

```
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo2"/>
```

What I want to do is to substitute the value field in each entry of the file by a random string with the format "nodoR" where R is an integer number selected between max_R and min_R. My question is whether this is possible using awk.

I am stuck with the following:

```
awk '/"trajectory"/ {sub(/"nodo[0-9]"/,"nodoR")}1' $XML_FILE
```

With the previous line I will substitute all the "node[0-9]" values by the same value "nodoR". This is not what I want, I want each line to be replaced by a random string, i.e. "nodoX" where X is random between max_R and min_R. However for that I should include the computation of the random X within the previous awk command. Is this possible ?

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can create a user-defined function and pass in the values as per your needs. Something like this -

```
awk 'function randInt(low, hi) {
x = rand()
y = (hi - low) + 1
z = int((x * y) + low)
return z} /"trajectory"/ {x=randInt(100,1000); sub(/"nodo[0-9]"/,"\"nodo"x"\"")}1' XML_FILE
```

**Execution:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat XML_FILE 
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo2"/>
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo2"/>
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo2"/>
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo2"/>
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo2"/>
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo2"/>
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo2"/>
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo2"/>
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo2"/>
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo2"/>

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk 'function randInt(low, hi) {
x = rand()
y = (hi - low) + 1
z = int((x * y) + low)
return z} /"trajectory"/ {x=randInt(100,1000); sub(/"nodo[0-9]"/,"\"nodo"x"\"")}1' XML_FILE
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo857"/>
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo455"/>
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo805"/>
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo819"/>
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo921"/>
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo277"/>
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo402"/>
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo792"/>
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo350"/>
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo599"/>
```

Comment: :) Thanks to you @shellter. All this learning is from following your answers on SO. Yours and the likes of Michael J. Barber, glenn jackman, Kent and few others.

Answer (score 0):

In awk, concatenation is your friend.

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand();};/"trajectory"/ {R=rand(); sub(/"nodo[0-9]"/,"nodo" R )}1' $XML_FILE
```

If you want a repeatable series of random numbers, then remove the BEGIN block with the srand().

Math heads will add exactly how you can get a random value between min and max numbers. It involves the '%' (modulo) operator for the max, but I don't remember now how to force a minumum, except with a test like `(R >= minVal)`. This would require a loop, so maybe there a more concise method.

I hope this helps.